# Difference between box.tpl and block.tpl in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

Looking for the Difference between box.tpl and block.tpl in Drupal. Need the context of usage and its appropriateness too

Answer (score 0):

`block.tpl.php` is responsible for theming blocks (those that you would find at `admin/build/block` in Drupal 6).

`box.tpl.php` is not used for anything specific, just to theme elements that need to be inside a box. Most notably by default it's used to add a wrapper around comments and search results.